# SQL - monthly average rather than daily average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called values that contains 3 columns - Location, value, date

I want to work out the average value per month

so far I have

```
SELECT Location, Avg(value), date  
FROM Value  
GROUP BY Location, date
```

This returns the average values but a value is entered on a daily basis so I have an average per day rather than per month, how can I achieve a monthly average?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @user1505127.  If you find an answer that works, please give credit by giving it a green-check. That's how we feel useful :)

Comment: What about year information?  If you only specify month, the same month in each year will be averaged together (ie AVG January in 2011 AND 2012, etc).  As opposed to including year information (so, AVG of January in 2012 is different than January in 2011, etc).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT    Location,
          Avg(value),
          month(date),
          year(date)
FROM      Value
GROUP BY  Location,
          month(date),
          year(date)
```

Comment: I think you're missing a comma after the first `month(date)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following, if you want month only grouping:

```
SELECT Location, Avg(value) AvgVal, Month(date) Mnth
FROM Value
GROUP BY Location, Month(date)
```

You can even use `GROUPING SETS`, which will `GROUP BY` Month, year, location and then give you a total for all:

```
SELECT Location, 
  Avg(value) AvgVal, 
  Month(dt) Mnth,
  Year(dt) Yr
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY 
  GROUPING SETS((Month(dt), Year(dt), Location), (Location));
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d75e8/10)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
     Location,
     year(date),
     month(date),
     Avg(value)
FROM
     Value
GROUP BY
     Location,
     year(date),
     month(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also do it as the following if you want to combine the dates into one column with the first of the month as the day.

```
SELECT    Location,
          Avg(value),
          DateFromParts(Year(date), Month(date) , 1) AS FirstOfMonthDate
FROM      Value
GROUP BY  Location,
          DateFromParts(Year(date), Month(date) , 1)
```